# C# System.__ComObjec - Shell32 ошибка на других ОС

Tags: c#, visual-studio

подключил библиотеку Shell32 к своему проекту через COM, я использую windows 7, на моем компьютере работает всё прекрасно. Но когда запускаю на компьютере с другой операционной системой(windows 10, 8). то программа не работает. Просмотрел ошибку через windbg, вот результат:

> **Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to
> interface type 'Shell32.Shell'. This operation failed because the
> QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
> '{34936BA1-67AD-4C41-99B8-8C12DFF1E974}' failed due to the following
> error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
> (E_NOINTERFACE)).**

Как мне исправить ошибку? Насколько я понял ссылка на shell32 при компиляции сохраняется только для windows 7, в то время как другие ОС используют более новую версию shell32 с другим идентификатором.

Вот пример кода:

```
[STAThread]    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var masslnk = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "*.lnk");
    foreach (string element in masslnk)
    {
        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
        Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(element));
        Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.Items().Item(Path.GetFileName(element));
        Shell32.ShellLinkObject currentLink = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
        currentLink.Arguments = "";
        currentLink.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие функыии библиотеки вы используете? Как подключаете? Покажите код.

Comment: Я использую shell32 для изменения параметров ярлыков (добавляю аргументи). Я пишу в visual studio, подключаю библиотеку в обозревателе - добавить сылку - во вкладке COM ставлю галочку на Microsoft Shell Controls.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, вставьте код. Так же укажите, какая версия .NET? Пробовали ли вы подключить библиотеку не через COM, а через DllImport? Вообще, мне не очень удобно вытягивать из вас информацию для решения вашего де вопроса.

Comment: Прекрасно вас понимаю. Код приложу позже версия .NET 4.0 . Также попробую через DllImport позже отпишу что по результатам.

Comment: Сразу стоп. Почему 4.0? Вам нужна поддержка Windows XP? Если нет, то смело меняйте версию целевого фреймворка на 4.7.2.

Comment: А почему нет? Мне важно чтоб программа запускалась без предустановки более новой версии .NET, поэтому выбрал 4.0 так как он присутствует почты на всех компьютерах. Простите если что-то не так понимаю, я ещё чайник в .NET и C#.

Comment: Потому что с этой древностью 13-летней давности даже я не возьмусь работать. Баг на баге. Ставьте 4.7.2 как целнвую версию, оно совместимо со всем из того что вы перечислили. Для верности удалите COM референс и переподключите заново, а еще лучше DllImport вместо COM.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо что уделяете внимание моему вопросу. Если я поставлю версию 4.7.2 но на компьютере будет стоять более старая версия .NET программа будет работать? Повторюсь что мне важен запуск программи без предустановок новых компонентов.

Comment: [Версии и зависимости платформы .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)

Comment: Если вы поставите 4.7.2, оно будет работать на всех системах начиная с Windows 7. Везде где была когда-либо установлена любая версия .NET Framework, она была обновлена автоматически до максимально поддерживаемой версии. Для Win7 это 4.7.2.

Comment: Если нужна поддержка Windows Vista и той самой неудачной версии Win8 (которая была принудительно обновлена до 8.1), в существовании копий которых в наши дни я в принципе сомневаюсь, то ставьте версию 4.6.

Comment: Добавил пример кода в вопрос. Изменил версию .NET и переподключил СОМ референс, ошибка осталась, код ошибки тот же. Питаюсь использовать DllImport но никак не могу понять как он работает. Буду благодарен за помощь по использовнии DllImport. Также в просторах интeрнета нашёл примеры кодов для DllImport shell32 [Сам сайт с примерами](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.Run).

Comment: А что делает ваш код то? Какую задачу он решает? Просто редактирует ярлык?

Comment: Да, но мне важно чтобы ярлык не пересоздавался и оставался на том же месте после редактирования.

Comment: [Вот что нашел](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp).

Comment: Прочитал, но никак не могу понять куда это всё писать в коде. Можете дать пример?